# Missing title bar when using wm manage and wm forget

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I am using `wm manage` and `wm forget` to dock and undock a frame from a Tk application.

When I undock the frame `f1`, sometimes the title bar of the view is not displayed. The frame does not undock correctly and so I can not handle it on the screen.

```
set f1 [winfo parent $w]
# get state of Dock button
set state [$T header state get DockBtn detach]

if {!$state} {
    puts "  -- detach, undock, deconnect"

    # detach the widget f1
    grid forget       $f1   
    wm manage       $f1
    wm protocol     $f1 WM_DELETE_WINDOW {}
    event generate  $f1 <<DetachedTab>>

    set DockState 0
} else {
    if {$DockState == 0} {
        puts "  -- attach, dock"
        wm forget $f1

        # add to my panedwindow f1
        $panedW add $f1 -width 300

        set DockState 1  
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to say by "bar" the title of the window.

Comment: You should edit your question rather than add comments stating changes. This is not a ttk question -- you can't manage ttk frames, only tk frames. You should really try and produce a minimal example that demonstrates the problem. This one is incomplete. Which version of Tk? What widget are you trying to manage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that you use `grid forget` to detach the frame from the parent when converting to a managed window. However you use `$panedW add` to re-attach it to the main application window. That suggests your parent is actually a panedwindow widget. This means the manager is not grid but panedwindow - you can test this using `winfo manager $f1`. If this is the case you have conflicting window management. You need to be consistent in both parts of the function.

Comment: Thank you, Yes It's a panedwindow `puts [winfo manager $f1]` = panedwindow. When I try to use `wm forget $f1` or `$panedW forget $f1`. It's better but the title is missing at the 4th click

Comment: Hello, So, I added `wm positionfrom $f1 user # to do not atach the window anywhere and let ther user (not the program) manage it in the screen` and `wm sizeform $f1 user` My window has at all times its title (so a bar to manage it on th screen). Thank you and sorry for my bad english